# Tree data structure for the implementation of a binomial option pricing model

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree, finance

I am starting an implementation of the binomial option pricing model. Under this model, the price of a stock is modeled as follows. At initial time, the price is given by S_0. At time n=1, the price either goes up or down. In the up state, the price at n=1 is u*S_0, and in the down state the price is d*S_0. At time n=2 each of these two prices "split" into up/down states. Corresponding to the first price, at time n=2 we get in the up state u^2*S_0 and in the down state u*d*S_0. Corresponding to the second price, we get in the up state d*u*S_0 and in the down state d^2*S_0. Since u*d*S_0 = d*u*S_0, at time n=2 we have three possible prices: u^2*S_0, u*d*S_0 = S_0 (we can assume that u*d = 1), and d^2*S_0. This model can be visualized as a a sort of "tree":

[image]

All the implementations of this model I've found generate these prices and store them in a numpy array as an upper triangular matrix. That's nice and all and I'm sure I could figure it out, but my instinct when I started thinking about this project was to use a tree data structure and implement the various option pricing formulas and such as recursive methods. However, I don't believe that the "tree" above is a binary tree in the data structure terminology because subtrees appear to have "multiple roots."

I have the following binary tree class:

```
class BinaryTree: 
    class Node: 
        def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
            self.val = val
            self.left = left
            self.right = right

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0
        self.root = None

    def pprint(self, width=64):
        height = self.height()
        nodes  = [(self.root, 0)]
        prev_level = 0
        repr_str = ''
        while nodes:
            n,level = nodes.pop(0)
            if prev_level != level:
                prev_level = level
                repr_str += '\n'
            if not n:
                if level < height-1:
                    nodes.extend([(None, level+1), (None, level+1)])
                repr_str += '{val:^{width}}'.format(val='-', width=width//2**level)
            elif n:
                if n.left or level < height-1:
                    nodes.append((n.left, level+1))
                if n.right or level < height-1:
                    nodes.append((n.right, level+1))
                repr_str += '{val:^{width}}'.format(val=n.val, width=width//2**level)
        print(repr_str)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def height(self):
        def height_rec(t):
            if not t:
                return 0
            else:
                return 1 + max(height_rec(t.left), height_rec(t.right))

        return height_rec(self.root)
    
    def add(self, val):
        assert(val not in self)
        def add_rec_notin(node):
            if not node: 
                return BinaryTree.Node(val)
            elif val < node.val: # adding to the left
                return BinaryTree.Node(node.val, left=add_rec_notin(node.left), right=node.right)
            else: # val > node.val, adding to the right
                return BinaryTree.Node(node.val, left=node.left, right=add_rec_notin(node.right))
            
        self.root = add_rec(self.root)
        self.size += 1
    
    def __iter__(self):
        def iter_rec(node):
            if node: 
                for x in iter_rec(node.left):
                    yield x
                for x in iter_rec(node.right):
                    yield x
        for x in iter_rec(self.root):
            yield x
```

I attempted to generate the prices at each time t and use the `add` method to build the price tree

```
T = 2     # time periods
S0 = 2    # initial stock prie
d = 0.9   # down factor
u = 1.1   # up factor

stock_tree = BinaryTree() 

stock_prices = []
for t in range(T+1): 
    lst = []
    for r in range(t+1):
        lst.append(S0 * (u ** r) * (d **(t-r)))
    stock_prices.append(lst)
    
for p in stock_prices: 
    for i in range(len(p)):
        stock_tree.add(round(p[i],3))
        
stock_tree.pprint()



                          2.0                               
          1.8                             2.2               
  1.62            1.98             -              2.42
```

I don't believe there is a way to do this with a binary tree data structure. Even if I tried adding the duplicate value 1.98 to the tree, it would not go into the blank spot above: it would be added as the right child of 1.98 on the left subtree.

Is there another data structure that could be useful here?

Comment: as you say, this diagram does not illustrate a binary tree, but rather a DAG: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph. From a quick glance, my instinct is that you might consider a Dynamic Programming approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming.